# to be to remember

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if I could say "Something is to remember"
For example:

> This trip is to remember

Is it grammatically correct? If it is, which part of the sentence is stressed?

Comment: What is the meaning that you would like the sentence to have? Is the example the whole sentence or part of one?

Comment: yes it is the whole sentence, the goal is to make some kind of short comment-type sentence

Comment: "This trip is memorable" or "This trip is worth remembering" would be more usual. You can use "to" in this way as far as I know, but it's not the usual way of expressing this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To signify that an event is particularly remarkable, the usual construct is:

- "*A night to remember*"
- "*This is a trip to remember*"
- "*It was a party to remember*"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so "is to remember" is a grammar error? I feel like I already heard that in a discussion

Comment: @CômeSchaeffer - it's fine, not an error.

Comment: We say "A [noun] to remember", but not that something "is to remember". It's not so much a grammatical error as just unidiomatic.

Comment: This is not what the question asks, whether or not OP realises the fact. We've already discussed the to-infinitive in its rare use as a complement after the copula: 'These burgers are to go' / 'That dress is to die for'. 'This one is to keep' could mean either that the speaker intends to keep the referent, or is saying that it would be foolish not to keep it. // As @Stuart F says, OP's example doesn't sound too familiar, but that doesn't classify it as unacceptable. // The to-infinitive as a noun complement (your suggestions) are far more common, but have been covered before.

Comment: The usual structure has been dealt with at [Noun + to-infinitive structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121374/noun-infinitive-verb-structure).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for your help, it makes more sense now!